# Windows Phone 8 Facebook Authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, windows-phone-8

I am working on an application for Windows Phone 8 and I'd like to give the possibility to the users to login with their Facebook account, so they won't have to create an account on my application.

I saw the Facebook SDK for .NET and decided to use it because it seems to be really efficient and popular.

As a beginner, I followed the tutorial in the doc of the SDK : http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/

I did the exact same thing that in the tutorial, everything is okay since I login. I click on the login button, I'm redirected to what they call the "FacebookLoginPage" in the tutorial (a .xaml with an empty grid so the webbrowser can fit in it), then appears the webbrowser with the Facebook page where I can type my login and password. After that, I'm redirected to the page that asks for permissions on my Facebook account, I click on OK. Everything is good so far.

And then comes my problem. I should be redirected to what they call the "LandingPage" in the tutorial, but instead of that I'm redirected to the facebook "login_success" (https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html‎) which displays "Success" and also a security warning, and then nothing happens anymore...

I thought something in my code was not right so I spend a couple of hours working on it, didn't find anything. So I tried to run the sample application that they provide in the doc of the website, I just modified the Facebook AppID in it (I've put mine), and same thing happened.
I also tried other things that I found on the Nokia Developer Wiki, same thing.

So I think something is wrong with my Facebook Application, but I can't find what it is...
Is anybody could give me some help ? I'm dying here :(

I apologize in advance for my english mistakes, and I wish you a good day !

**UPDATE :** I finally did it following this tutorial http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application

Comment: No code - no answer... Your options: post small sample of code that does not work, find someone who can seat next to you and help, give up or try other samples.

Comment: "I did the exact same thing that in the tutorial"
"So I tried to run the sample application that they provide in the doc of the website"

What is the point of posting code in that case ? You don't want to answer me, that doesn't mean other peoples won't. Actually, I had my answer below...

Comment: Sample code is needed to be inline to make post a good question on SO - what if the site you are linking changes code and your post no longer useful for other? Side note: If you get an good hint in an answer you should at very least vote it up, if it is indeed answers your question - mark it as answer.

Comment: I can't vote up because I don't have enough "reputation" on StackOverflow.

Comment: (I thought you can always upvote answers to your own question... which is apparently not true :( )

Answer (score 1):

The redirect to "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html‎" should contain the accessToken as a url parameter, so if you allow navigating to this url it is indeed a security risk as it exposes the AccessToken. You need to listen for the 'Navigating' event from the WebBrowser control and if the browser is navigating to "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html‎" then you need to cancel the navigation and get the AccessToken from the url parameter.

UPDATE:
It looks like FB changed their OAuth login response from ...login_success.html#access_token= to ...login_success.html?#access_token= There is now a "?" character before the "#" character.

Comment: I think the Facebook SDK for .NET should do it itself. I did the exact same thing that they say in the documentation...

Comment: I think the facebook SDK is written by a third party so if Facebook made changes, as Matt stated above, then the SDK could easily break.
I do a lot of coding for access to cloud services and I always use the http rest api for this reason.

Comment: Okay, I see.
Do you any tutorial that I could follow ? It's new for me !

Comment: WOW, I just ran some test code and unless I am going crazy (which is possible) it looks like FB changed their OAuth login response from ...login_success.html#access_token=<token> to ...login_success.html?#access_token=<token>  There is now a "?" character before the "#" character. That would explain why the library you are using did not correctly parse the access token.

Comment: Oh yeah that could make sense. I'll wait a couple of days and retry then.
Thank you Jon !

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in a lot of apps in the store recently so it's probably not you doing something wrong but rather a change by Facebook which hasn't yet been reflected in the SDK.

Have you tried using Windows Azure Mobile Services Authentication instead?

See guides at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/register-for-facebook-authentication/ and http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/register-for-facebook-authentication/ for more information.

Comment: No I didn't try Windows Azure Mobile Services Authentication, I'll look at that.

Thank you for the information !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the LoginButton control of the Facebook SDK .NET for WindowsPhone and have the same issue.

I Fix it, downloading the project from github [Facebook-WinClient-Sdk](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk) and changing the line 186 of FacebookSessionClient class, for this one:

Uri endUri = new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?#access_token");

The team of facebook sdk for .net will be fix this issue for sure, but i have a demo today and need it works!

Comment: You helped me a lot but I'm still in trouble !
I changed the "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" by "https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?#access_token" but it did not change.
After that I also changed it in `parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";`
After that, I can login but I have an error saying the the URL I gave is not authorized by the application configuration.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Ah, so that supports what I found out yesterday about the change to the OAuth redirect (listed in the comments to my answer on this tiopic). The FB documentation still shows the old OAuth redirect so it must be an error on their part, so I would assume that they will change it back when they realize the error.